# Reorder columns in small devices Bootstrap 4

Tags: grid, bootstrap-4

Unfortunately Bootstrap in Beta version drops `push-*` and `pull-*`classes, so I don't have idea how to reorder columns in xs and sm devices from:

> [column_1] [column_2] [column_3]

to:

> [column_1][column_3]
>
> [column_2]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are new [Reordering](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#reordering) helper classes.
Place the divs in HTML as you want them to appear in mobile:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
      [column_1]
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 order-md-12">
      [column_3]
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 order-md-1">
      [column_2]
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

[column_1] will stay first and unordered. Reorder [column_3] with `.order-md-12`(will be last for md-size and up) and [column_2] `.order-md-1`(will be first for md-size and up)

Check [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wpL1gp0b/30/)

Comment: In xs devices (after add col-xs-*) columns are one under the other. Any fix ?

Comment: @Knowledge there is no more  `col-xs-*`, just ` col-*`. I am updating my answer

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks